# Update similar name atributes in python class

Tags: python, class, setattribute

I want to update my similar name atributes but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 12, in <module>
NameError: name 'name_0_' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
class Test:
    name_0_1 = 0 
    name_0_2 = 0   
    name_0_3 = 0 
    name_0_4 = 0


my_object = Test()
my_list_value = range(1,8)

for i in my_list_value:
  print(setattr(my_object, name_0_ + str(i), i))
```

Comment: Instead of having a bunch of similar class variables, why not stick them in a list called `name_0` then you can access what you want with the index values and iterate through it easier.

Comment: It needs to be `setattr(my_object, 'name_0_' + str(i), i)`. You forgot your quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setattr()` requires you to pass a string as the second parameter. This can clearly be seen in the [Python documentation for `setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

> [...] The arguments are an **object, a string and an arbitrary value**. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, setattr(x, 'foobar', 123) is equivalent to x.foobar = 123.

So use:

```
setattr(my_object, 'name_0_' + str(i), i)
```

Instead of:

```
setattr(my_object, name_0_ + str(i), i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The setattr second parameter must be a string:

```
class Test:
    name_0_1 = 0 
    name_0_2 = 0   
    name_0_3 = 0 
    name_0_4 = 0


my_object = Test()
my_list_value = range(1,8)

for i in my_list_value:
  print(setattr(my_object, 'name_0_' + str(i), i))
```